# Add pdf icon for all links using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have over 1K links in a html page, How do I add a pdf icon just before the link using jquery.

Thanks
Jean

[update]
@pekka
I have added the icon, the icon displays, but it is under the text extreme right.  I cannot move the icon with left, or padding-left , because the icon is placed as background-image.  Using left: or padding-left moves the links.

Comment: This is better solved with CSS, but might not work in e.g. IE6.

Comment: No need for jQuery, this will work fine with CSS. Possible duplicate of [What is the standard way to add an icon to a link with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014469/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-an-icon-to-a-link-with-css)

Comment: @Jean see the duplicate link, the first code block (with `padding-left`) will work fine. Adding an answer here because the dupe is not 100% clear

Comment: @felix @pekka I cannot add a new class to all the links. there has to be a easier way?

Comment: You don't need a new class. Use the same selector you would use to the select the elements in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS:

```
a { /* <---- or a class selector to limit the rule to some links */ 

      padding-left: 24px; /* or the width of your icon */
      background-image: url(....);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: left center; /* Adjust if needed */
   }
```

if your icon's height differs from the links' height, use either `padding-top` / `padding-bottom` or `line-height` to adjust.

Comment: @Jean this will work - you'll have to show some code if it doesn't

Comment: Its working, now I got to work on the permissions, did a chmod 777 on images. Got all the icons at the end of the link

Comment: @Jean it's a bit hard to understand what you mean without seeing what happens. If you have multi-line links, try `left top` to force the icon to the beginning of the text

Comment: @Jean I'd need to see that live to understand what you mean. `background-position` should place the image to the left. Can you post a JSFiddle example?

Comment: @Jean I don't know, I think you have to upload them separately. However in your case, you have a CSS definition overriding the first definition in `a:link`: `background: url(images/14.png) no-repeat top right;`. Then it's clear it'll place them there

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without using JQuery.

```
a[href$='.pdf'] // this is for all the link which end .pdf extension. so you don;t need jquery  
{  
padding-left: 20px;  
background: url(images/icon_pdf.gif) center left no-repeat;  
}
```